# Mapping an array of objects without jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
showsList = [{
    "location": "ELM",
    "date": 04 - 03 - 16,
    "stage": "BLUE",
    "name": "MotorBlur",
    "id": 106
}, {
    "location": "KRAFT",
    "date": 04 - 03 - 16,
    "stage": "ORANGE",
    "name": "donotdelete",
    "id": 107
}];
```

(theres alot more data but for the sake of simplicity; you get the point). Im used to mapping arrays like so...

```
{showList.map((show, idx) => (
```

but this doesn't apply as the values aren't directly accessable like normal array values would be. How can I map an array to retrieve the data inside the objects? (written in jsx syntax) Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: How are the values not directly accessible? What problem are you having?

Comment: @FizzyTea I just want to know how to get the data inside the objects. Since its objects inside an array, I'm not sure how to get the data with just a regular .map() call

Comment: @Modelesq You access the data in an object by writing `obj[key]`, e.g. `obj["location"]` or `obj["date"]`.

Comment: Describe your required output and what you've tried so far. I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you're just looping through the array use `forEach`. Please give a clear problem statement. SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access them using a for loop through the array and using object notation thereafter, but if you'd like to use `map` try something like this:

```
showsList.map(function(obj){
  for(var item in obj){
    console.log("key: "+ item)
    console.log("value: " + obj[item]);
  }
});
```

here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzNMeW)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use exactly what you started to write in your description:

```
showsList.map((show, idx) => {
    console.log(show.location)
    console.log(show.date)
    console.log(show.stage)
    console.log(show.name)
    console.log(show.id)
})
```